# Installing ESLink on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, installation, sas

How can I add to eclipse the  SAS plugin [ESLink](http://eslink.sourceforge.net/) ? I cannot get the update site to work. If the update is offline, ESLink has [published](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eslink/files/) a file, but how do I get it installed? Anyone else managed to get it working?

---

Well, at least I earned the [tumbleweed](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed?userid=188368) badge! sigh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked for me.  It took a few minutes before it loaded.  I downloaded it from the update site.

http://www.anaxima.com/eslink-updatesite

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, here are the instructions on how to install the plugin from a local ZIP archive. The same procedure should apply for any Eclipse plugin, not just Eslink.

(This has been tested with Eclipse Helios.)

1. Open `Window --> Preferences`
   dialog.
2. Select `Install/Update -->
   Available Software Sites`.   `Add`
   new site. Give it a name, for
   example "Eslink (local)", and point
   `Archive` at the local ZIP file you
   have on your computer. Close the
   `Preferences` dialog.
3. Open `Help -->
   Install New Software...` dialog.
   Select the local update site you
   just created from the `Work with`
   selection list. You should see a
   list of items available for install:
   [image]
4. Select the item you want
   to install (Eslink 0.8.1 in this
   case) and click `Next`.
5. Review
   details, click `Next`.
6. Accept the
   license agreement, click `Finish`.
7. A security warning will appear during
   installation, mentioning about the
   fact that the installation contains
   unsigned content. You will have to
   accept to be able to finish the
   installation.
8. Finally, restart
   Eclipse when asked.